# Adding Bean to Start Up of Spring Boot Using Byte Buddy

Tags: java, spring-boot, instrumentation, byte-buddy, javaagents

Am just trying to instrument my `spring-boot` application. I would like to add a `@Bean` into the main class. The intention is to initialize the tracer as part of the `bean`

Initially Tried the below

```
new AgentBuilder.Default()
                    .type(ElementMatchers.nameStartsWith("my.package.name"))
                    .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module) -> builder.visit(
                            Advice.to(BootUpInterceptor.class)
                                    .on(hasMethodName("main"))

                            )


                    ).installOn(instrumentation);
```

```
@Advice.OnMethodEnter
    static void initializeTracerAtMain(@Advice.Origin String methodName) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Initializing Tracer in  Method "+methodName);

// Tracer Initializers 
    }
```

Basically am initializing configuration for `jaeger` tracer. This is working but I need to use `GlobalTracer` to register the tracer.

How can I add this initializer as a bean to my existing `main classs` ? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Java configuration class, you could instrument it and add a `@Bean`-annotated method using `defineMethod`. Alternatively, you could instrument the constructor of an application context and register the bean explicitly in an exit-advice.

Comment: Can't I add the `@Bean` annotated method inside my application main class using `defineMethod`. Can you point me to some example?